# Akka light-weight thread

Tags: akka

In akka documentation:

> The good news is that Akka actors conceptually each have their own light-weight thread, which is completely shielded from the rest of the system.

What is a light-weight thread? Aren't threads considered to be expensive resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They key word here is 'conceptually': indeed JVM/OS threads are (relatively) expensive resources, and for this reason Akka is not implemented with a thread per actor - that would be too heavy.

Akka does make sure each actor only processes one message at a time. This means 'inside the actor' your don't have to worry about concurrently and that is what meant by the statement that 'conceptually' you can think of an actor running on a 'lightweight thread' (though internally it's not implemented using a thread per actor).